# Azure App Service doesn't run Asp.Net Core app from VSTS

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When publishing a asp.net core app using VSTS (VS2017 build task) the app won't start, build and release works without error.

**Symptoms**:

- App doesn't start when you access the public url through the browser. No logs
  when enabling even with `verbose` logging.
- When using Publish from Visual Studio it works perfectly.
- When downloading the `wwwroot` folder using Kudu-tools the `web.exe`
  starts without a problem and runs just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** It turns out that publishing with Visual Studio 2017 adds a `Web.Config` file with handler mappings to the deployment with the following content which adds the default handler mapping for `aspNetCore`.

The strangest with this is that the `Web.Config` file isn't visible in Debug console, just if you download the `wwwroot` folder from Kudu tools. Something is strange here in the tooling even if it clear that the handler mapping is needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\Web.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 50547f5d-25a5-4720-9216-92d42583b679-->
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not visible in Debug Console? It's a completely normal file, and if you use FTP or Kudu Console you will see it under `d:\home\site\wwwroot`. I'm also puzzled why it didn't get published from VSTS, as that's done as part of the .NET Core msbuild support.

Comment: I mean it doesn't show up. I only see the file if I download the folder as zip. Yes - that's why I posted here. Really strange.